# Empty ID after when saving model to database

Tags: django

When I add a book model to the database, and then look at the book table in SQL Database Browser, it shows the id field as being blank.

It's strange because I have 1000 items in the table. I don't know what happened, because ~390 of them have their ID populated. The others have their id blank.

Shouldn't the id field be essentially the primary key? How could it have been populated in some cases and not other cases.

Note1: In the past I have manually deleted records -- not sure if that might be an issue.
Note2: When I `print "newbook id:", repr(newbook.id)`, the id is different than the primary key seen in SQL Database Browser.

This is what I see:

[image]

The relevant code is below:

Model:

```
class Books (models.Model):
    bookname=models.CharField(_('bookname'), max_length=255)
    publisher=models.CharField(_('publisher'), max_length=255)
    description=models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    coverart = models.ImageField(upload_to="art", blank=True, null=True)
    source=models.TextField(blank=True) #source of where it came from
    last_updated=models.DateTimeField(_('added'), default=datetime.now)
    category_id=models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='cat')
    model = models.ManyToManyField ('model', related_name = 'model')
    shortdesc=models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    url = models.TextField(_('url'), blank=True)
    uid = models.IntegerField()`
```

Code that saves a book:

```
try: 
    exists = Books.objects.get(bookname=bookname)
except Books.DoesNotExist:
    print "book does not exist -- adding now"
    newbook=Books(bookname=bookname, uid = uid, source='Mysourceofbooks',     publisher=publisher, description = description, shortdesc=shortdesc, url = url)
    newbook.save()
    for cat in category_ids:
        newbook.category_id.add(cat)
else:
    print "log: we found the book in the DB already"`
```

Comment: Which "id" are you talking about? The `id` field Django adds? Or your `uid` field? Can you show an example of code which results in a book with an "empty ID"?

Comment: Yes the `id` field that Django adds. The code is the 2nd piece of code when I do newbook.save()

Comment: So, to be clear, if you used: `newbook = Book(...); newbook.save(); print "newbook id:", repr(newbook.id)`, you would see `newbook id: None`?

Comment: Oh... no that shows up with an ID. But in the database when I open it in SQLite Database Browser the table has an empty id field.

Comment: Ah. See, that's the kind of information that would have been good for you to include in the question ;)

Comment: And if you later try to load the `Book`, does it have an id? Because, if it does, this seems like a problem with the SQLite Database Browser and not Django. Please edit your question to describe *exactly* the problem you're seeing, including screen shots or a database dump or something similar.

Comment: But that ID doesn't show up in the database. The ID field is blank and the primary key given is different. Ex: 1001 is the value in my database. And when I write that command you wrote I get 1177.

Comment: So please edit your question to demonstrate exactly the problem you're seeing, including screen shots or a database dump or something similar. Possibly it would be useful to run something like `sqlite db.sqlite3 "SELECT * FROM myapp_book"` to take the dump.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12461/discussion-between-user1328021-and-david-wolever)

Comment: Oh, wow, alright, that is an odd problem. So, a couple things to double check: is the `id` column *actually* a primary key? You can find that in the [database structure](https://img.skitch.com/20120612-8b3x879mmh31nxjkdfkwrckb9c.png). And the *rest* of the rows — are they otherwise correct (ex, do they have the expected `bookname` and stuff)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion in chat: the `id` column in the `Book` table somehow managed to lose its status as a `PRIMARY KEY`. Set that back and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

First, you can use function [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for testing/saving model.
It return tuple - object, created.

If you can save object with new id: set object.pk to None, and save it.
In your code is more crazy thinks. => Book is better name for model that Books.

What do you think with this:

```
for cat in category_ids:
    print cat
    newbook.category_id.add(cat)
```

What is category_ids variable?
Why name "category_id" for ManyToMany?

Comment: Your critiques are valid, but they do not answer the question. Please do not use the “add an answer” button to post something that isn't an answer.

Comment: The category_id is an integer that I am pulling in from an API

Comment: And I in fact did use 'Book'. I changed the model quickly because I am working on something confidential and didn't want to have really specific variables for what I'm working on.